# Android - Checking value from an SQLite DB table

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I'm trying to read data from newly deleted SQLite db table row.

Basically my program will delete a row when a certain activity is loaded, and I want to check the value inside the row.

This is my `get` code :

```
public String getSlot() {
            String slots = new String();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT,
                chosenSlotColumn, null, null, null, null, null);

            if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                slots = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return slots;
          }
```

I've used these codes to delete the value :

```
public static final String DELETE_SLOT = "DELETE FROM "
            + TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT + " WHERE "
            + "_ID = " + CHOSEN_ID + ";";

public void deleteSlotSQL()
      {
          database.execSQL(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.DELETE_SLOT);
      }
```

And this is my condition to set a `TextView`value :

```
if(slots == null)
            {
                chosenSlotView.setText("You have not parked");
            }
            else
            {
                chosenSlotView.setText("You are parked in : " + slots);
            }
```

At first, I thought that once the only row is deleted, `getSlot()` would return null, but it seems that it's not null from this `Log.d` I ran :

```
if(slots != null)
            {
               Log.d("notnull","not null dude");
            }else
            {
               Log.d("null","Yay null");
            }
```

The `log` returns "not null dude"..

Any suggestion on how to get the `slots` value so I can set the `TextView` value??

Comment: First off all you should avoid using logs like "not null dude", you will find them funny and suggestive but after a while we won t be able to write clean and professional code .

Comment: Nahh, that log was only debug purpose, I was just checking it out. It's going to be deleted later or changed into a more professional sentence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `slots` definitely not null because of this :
    String slots = new String();

it should be

```
 String slots = null;
Cursor cursor = database.query(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT,
                chosenSlotColumn, null, null, null, null, null);

            if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                slots = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return slots;
```

EDIT :

Nevermind that `String slot = null`,

Try using :

```
if(slots.isEmpty())
        {
            chosenSlotView.setText(notParked);
        }
        else
        {
            chosenSlotView.setText(isParked + slots);
        }
```

Comment: But inside `if` clause, there's `slots = cursor.getString(0);` How to obtain the value of `getString(0)`?

Comment: can you provide the ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT string define ?

Comment: It is `chosen_parking_slot`, could it be.. This is the culprit?

Comment: Tried directly using `chosenSlotView.setText(slots);` outside `if`, but it doesn't show any output

Comment: try chosenSlotView.setText("test text :" +slots); because slots could be an empty String, like "";

Comment: Yes it does not show anything after the colons, like there's nothing after it, not even a space.. So it's an empty string? So I should use `if(slots == "")` ?

Comment: as I can see , you delete only one row by CHOSEN_ID , it mean your chosenSlotColumn could not be empty after that ( because it may have more than one item) and your slq command database.query(ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT,
                chosenSlotColumn, null, null, null, null, null); will get all item from chosenSlotColumn
check cursor.count()

Comment: never use == for check object equality, String has the method name isEmpty. 
if(slots!=null && !slots.isEmpty()){
chosenSlotView.setText(slots);
}

Comment: I tried dropping the table entirely and recreating it where necessary which is in the `MainActivity`. The class which I used to delete SQL data is now used to drop the table entirely and recreating it entirely. All recreation uses `if not exists`. AND I flipped the `if` from checking if slot is filled to the other way around and it worked.. Should've known! Ahahhaa

Answer (score 1):

First off all you should avoid using logs like "not null dude", you will find them funny and suggestive but after a while we won t be able to write clean and professional code.
My second advice is to use constants instead of hadcoded strings . Create a class Constants and add there strings

```
   public static final String NOT_PARKED = "You have not parked"
```

My third advice is to take a look at ormlite http://logic-explained.blogspot.ro/2011/12/using-ormlite-in-android-projects.html

If the logs are ok , maybe there is a problem with textview . Try putting a text in textview before the condition to check if will get set . Check the layout file also .

Comment: Ah yes, I've changed them into constants.. I thought that it'd be convenient for me, but yeah, modularity in mind, that was a wrong decision.. The `TextView` is okay, it still show value gained from here `chosenSlotView.setText("You are parked in : " + slots);`